# Firebase deploy stucks / hangs without error message

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

The command `Firebase deploy` always stucks when I run it.

Here is the verbose info:

```
    $ firebase deploy --token "SOMETOKEN" --debug
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Command:      /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase deploy --token SOMETOKEN --debug
CLI Version:  3.0.0
Platform:     darwin
Node Version: v5.0.0
Time:         Tue May 24 2016 14:25:31 GMT+0800 (CST)
----------------------------------------------------------------------

> command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase"]
> refreshing access token with scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase"]
>>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token refresh_token=SOMETOKEN, client_id=XXXXXX-XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com, client_secret=XXXXXX, grant_type=refresh_token, scope=email openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase
<<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 cache-control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, pragma=no-cache, expires=Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT, date=Tue, 24 May 2016 06:25:33 GMT, vary=X-Origin, Origin,Accept-Encoding, content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, x-content-type-options=nosniff, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-xss-protection=1; mode=block, server=GSE, alternate-protocol=443:quic, alt-svc=quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25", accept-ranges=none, connection=close
>>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/hackdaychat
<<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 server=nginx, date=Tue, 24 May 2016 06:25:34 GMT, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, content-length=109, connection=close, x-content-type-options=nosniff, strict-transport-security=max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains, cache-control=no-cache, no-store
>>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/hackdaychat/tokens
<<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 server=nginx, date=Tue, 24 May 2016 06:25:36 GMT, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, content-length=423, connection=close, x-content-type-options=nosniff, strict-transport-security=max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains, cache-control=no-cache, no-store
```

As you can see, I tried it with a token I have created before via `firebase login:ci`.

Without a token it is the same result.

I have also created the local Firebase project. There was no error during `Firebase init`.

`Firebase --list` works fine. `FireBase login` and `Firebase logout` works fine.

**Some additional info:**

- $ node -v -->  v5.0.0
- $ npm -v --> 3.3.6
- $ firebase -V --> 3.0.0
- OS: OS X 10.11.4
- Location: Shanghai, but using Proxy to Singapur.
- Access to Firebase website works fine.
- I have owner rights on the project I am using
- I try to deploy some kind of empty project. Means: My public folder only contains `index.html` and `404.html`.

Anyone got an idea what could go wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I got similar problem

Try

```
firebase logout
```

then

```
firebase login
```

it's works on my case. Once i logged in it's seem firebase app required extra permissions

also

```
npm update -g firebase-tools
```

Comment: Even thought I've updated firebase tools to 3.0.2, I got the same result.

Comment: When you do firebase logout and firebase login .  Do you see the Google consent screen asking for permission?  I assume they required more permissions

Comment: I do see the screen. And I always click on "allow". So I guess it should have all permission that are needed ?!

Comment: This also helped when 'firebase serve' was hanging. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Same here

firebase login and logout work fine. Same with init.

Also tried with and without a token. Same result as described by Frank.

I am behind a corporate proxy.

- node -v --> v4.4.2
- firebase --version --> 3.0.1
- npm -v --> 2.15.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is the right way to do it, but it seems to get it to work for me.

1. I went to the Google Cloud dashboard. (https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard)
2. I clicked the dropdown menu on the top left and clicked on "Cloud Storage"
3. I selected all of the folders in the bucket and deleted all of them. (It looks like it was storing old versions of the app that I had tried to upload and failed to upload).
4. After that, I ran: firebase deploy --only functions

It worked for me. I hope this works for you. I know how frustrating it was for me to not be able to upload my app to Firebase functions.